# How to override the maximized event of an UWP app

Tags: uwp

My UWP app is a fullscreen app. And when I click the app Window, then its Top-Right corner icon will be shown as in the first picture below.

When I drag the app Window, then it will become like the 2nd picture below.

For the 2nd picture, when I click the maximized icon, it cannot turn back to fullscreen mode. And I hope to override the method(event handler), so that I can add codes to change to fullscreen mode.

Is it possible and how?
Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to override the maximized event of an UWP app

Great question, but unfortunately there is no such method could be overrided to edit the default maximum button behavior, it is controlled with system level. In general we often make a entry full screen button on the page, if we exit full screen model, we could click the attached button to entry the full screen again. And we have code sample provided, please check [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FullScreenMode) for more info.

```
private void ToggleFullScreenModeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    if (view.IsFullScreenMode)
    {
        view.ExitFullScreenMode();
        rootPage.NotifyUser("Exiting full screen mode", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
        isLastKnownFullScreen = false;
        // The SizeChanged event will be raised when the exit from full screen mode is complete.
    }
    else
    {
        if (view.TryEnterFullScreenMode())
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Entering full screen mode", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            isLastKnownFullScreen = true;
            // The SizeChanged event will be raised when the entry to full screen mode is complete.
        }
        else
        {
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Failed to enter full screen mode", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For always put my app in fullscreen, I used the code of Nico Zhu with a Timer

```
private void TimerTickFullSreen()
{
    var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
    if (!view.IsFullScreenMode)
    {
        if (view.TryEnterFullScreenMode())
        {
            
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}

private void StartFullScreenSurvey()
{
    TimerFullScreen.Tick += (ss, ee) =>
    {
        if (TimerFullScreen.Interval.Ticks == 1000)
        {

            TimerTickFullSreen();

        }
    };
    TimerFullScreen.Interval = new TimeSpan(1000);
    TimerFullScreen.Start();
}
```

And use the function In My MainPage and stop whenever I change for another page.
I don't know if It will handle all situations, but for now it works pretty well.